# How to contol all elements on form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, foreach, controls

try to enable or disable some elements on my form (check boxes and textboxes)
Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7182849/2012219) , and remake a littlу bit this code

code:

```
    private void checkBoxEnableHotKeys_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBoxEnableHotKeys.Checked)
        {
            EnableControls(this.Controls, true);
        } //works perfect
        if (!checkBoxEnableHotKeys.Checked)
        {
            EnableControls(this.Controls, false);
        } //disable all controls
    }

    private void EnableControls(Control.ControlCollection controls, bool status)
    {
        foreach (Control c in controls)
        {   
            c.Enabled = status;         
            if (c is MenuStrip)
            {
                c.Enabled = true;
            }
            if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                EnableControls(c.Controls, status);
            }
        }
        checkBoxEnableHotKeys.Enabled = true; //not work 
    }
```

where i made mistake? and why `checkBoxEnableHotKeys.Enabled = true;` not work? (- during debagging this part of code passing with false - and operation `=` not work - false before and false after ...)

Comment: What actually do you want to do? If you want to disable some controls, remember that **Disabling a control will also disabling all its child controls**

Comment: check `checkBoxEnableHotKeys`'s parent is disabled. if yes then you've enable its parent in order to enable the child

Comment: oh! thanks ! add `tableLayoutPanel1.Enabled = true;` before `checkBoxEnableHotKeys.Enabled = true;` - now it's work. -  Disabling a control will also disabling all its child controls  - NOTED, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I like the methods that return all child controls of a form - including nested controls.

From: [Foreach Control in form, how can I do something to all the TextBoxes in my Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499049/foreach-control-in-form-how-can-i-do-something-to-all-the-textboxes-in-my-form)

I like the answer:

The trick here is that Controls is not a List<> or IEnumerable but a ControlCollection.

I recommend using an extension of Control that will return something more..queriyable ;)

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> All(this ControlCollection controls)
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls)
        {
            foreach (Control grandChild in control.Controls.All())
                yield return grandChild;

            yield return control;
        }
    }
```

Then you can do :

```
foreach(var textbox in this.Controls.All().OfType<TextBox>)
{
    // Apply logic to the textbox here
}
```

Comment: Heh, I wished I realized you could get that OfType<type> property like that at my old job. On numerous projects I had a recursive method that'd iterate over all the controls / controls' children and perform a ton of different actions based on the type. This would've made it so much cleaner.