# Enable all controls on a Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to enable all controls on a Panel. I can loop through the Panel like below.
This doesn't touch all the components though, just the top level ones.
How do I do this? ([This is not the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182821/how-to-enable-all-controls-on-a-form))

```
private void LoopThroughAllControls(System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < panel.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        panel.Controls[i].Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

`ToolStrip` code that adds `ToolStripButton` items:

```
this.toolStripContractor.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
this.tsbContractor_AddFile,
this.tsbContractor_View,
this.tsbContractor_Delete});
```

Comment: You need to make that recursive.

Comment: I was trying that but not getting very far. What Class with the input parameter be?

Comment: Use the base `Control` class.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you only need to do `Panel.Enabled = true` and it will automatically enable/disable all child controls anyway. You shouldn't need to manually enable/disable all children.

Comment: Look the like solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186828/loop-through-all-controls-on-a-form-even-those-in-groupboxes/35557077#35557077

Answer (score 5):

All you have to do is set the Panel's `Enabled` property to `true` or `false`.

From MSDN's page on the [`Enabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

> When a container control has its enabled property set to false, all its contained controls are disabled, as well. For example, if the user clicks on any of the controls contained in a disabled GroupBox control, no events are raised.

If, however, you choose to go with a recursive method, here is how to write it:

```
void SetEnabledAllChildrenOf(Control control, bool enabled)
{
    control.Enabled = enabled;
    foreach(Control c in control.Controls)
    {
        SetEnabledAllChildrenOf(c, enabled);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm having some difficulty and it may be the same difficulty I was having with setting the panel Enabled property to true ... it appears that buttons (i.e. items) on a ToolsStrip are not child controls.

Comment: @AlLelopath I can't help with code I can't see. If you can edit your question in include an [mcve] including the designer generated code then someone might be able to help you.

Comment: The code is your recursive method above. When it gets to the ToolStrip on the Panel, it thinks that Toolstrip does not have any children, so the recursion stops, so to speak. I've added to my original question the code that adds items to the ToolStrip.

Comment: ToolStrip items belongs to the `Items` property, since they are not inheriting `Control` the can't be referenced as `Control`. However, once you set the `ToolStrip`'s `Enabled` property to `false`, all it's items should be disabled with it.